# Rails 2.3.x use bleeding edges gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

In rails 3 you can use bleeding edge gems like: `gem "devise", :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"`. How do you do that with config.gem in rails 2.3.x?

Comment: Why don't you use bundler in your project?

Comment: I'd love to but I couldn't get it to work on rails 2.3.8 with Heroku.

Comment: I was able to get bundler/2.3.8/herkou working but BrowserCMS doesn't like bundler >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to use bundler on rails 2.3.x or switch to rails 3.

Heroku's docs are helpful: http://docs.heroku.com/bundler

Answer (score 0):

For that specific example I think you can do:

```
config.gem 'devise', :source => 'http://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
```

Comment: I think source specifies where the gem is hosted.  It used to be that you could put github or gemcutter in there. Now it's just gemcutter.  Also, when I tried that and ran rake gems:install it didn't install anything new.  I'd expect to see it download the project from github like bundle install does in rails 3.